# System Overlay Detector

Tags: android, android-security

Is there a way to detect within my own app that a Screen Overlay is currently present? For example, I see in the settings that they detect it: [image]

I would like to know if there is a way to detect it myself within my own app.

Answer (score 4):

Android [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) documentation offers clear ways :

> To enable touch filtering, call setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(boolean)
>   or set the android:filterTouchesWhenObscured layout attribute to true.
>   When enabled, the framework will discard touches that are received
>   whenever the view's window is obscured by another visible window. As a
>   result, the view will not receive touches whenever a toast, dialog or
>   other window appears above the view's window.
>
> For more fine-grained control over security, consider overriding the
>   onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(MotionEvent) method to implement your
>   own security policy. See also FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED.

Also refer to this [sample code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/SecureView.java).

Comment: Doesn't quite do it in this case.

Comment: In Android Q, they added [FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED) which detects overlays even outside of the touched area.

Comment: hellowill89 wants to detect the overlay BEFORE anybody touches anything. I have a similar problem with one of my apps. Some customers claim that a button does not respond to touch sometimes. The OnClickListener has no real potential for errors. I suspect that another (erroneous) app has an overlay that covers my button. To prove this, a corresponding detection would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan using a11y.

Comment: @hellowill89, @dev, @Mircel Bro, @The incredible jan, @FEBRYAN ASA PERDANA FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED or FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED is not working in above Android 11. Any idea to resolve this?? `event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED` or `event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED` always return zero in Android 11 and above devices. So this is not working. Raised a question regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988666/prevent-from-tapjacking-is-not-working-in-above-android-11-devices. If you have any idea please suggest me..