# How to detect a screen overlay on android

Tags: android, security, overlay

Is there any way to detect if a screen overlay is present over my app on android? Or at least if there is a way to prevent screen overlays over my app?

I found an open source app that is designed to help protect from screen overlays, which seems to be capable of detecting whether any screen overlay happened, so it should be possible? But to figure out how it works would require going through a lot of hard to understand code.
link to app: https://github.com/geeksonsecurity/android-overlay-protection

A similar question was already asked on stack overflow [Detecting Android screen overlays programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197671/detecting-android-screen-overlays-programmatically) but it has not been answered yet...

Thank you,

Comment: If not answered, I would suggest to put a bounty on it. (Sorry, I just saw you lack reputation points.)

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55076521/238753) for how Android M's settings app does it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System Overlay Detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076758/system-overlay-detector)