# Prevent from TapJacking is not working in Above Android 11+ devices

Tags: android

I am using the following code to prevent from tapJacking.

```
@Override
    public boolean onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(MotionEvent event) {
        if (((event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED)
                || (event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED) == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED) {
            
            //Showing popup
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It is working in below Android 10 devices. From Android 11 this is not working. Any idea to prevent tap jacking in Android 11+ devices.